# NinjaTrader - Writting to MemoryStream then to Disk

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, file, io

I would like to make the below code more efficient by writing all text(CSV) to memory before writing to disk. The CSV file could have upwards of 10,000 or rows. With the current code, it opens and closes the file for R/W each time. There must be a better way.   I am calling the WriteToCSV2 on each OnBarUpdate. The file on disk after it runs is approx. 10MB so there is no issue storing the entire contents of in memory before writing to disk.

This is part of a NinjaScript for Ninjatrader.

```
private void WriteToCSV2()
{

    if(CurrentBar <= BarsRequiredToPlot + LookBack) return;
        
    StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder logEntry = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder signalCode = new StringBuilder();

    string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath,fileName);
    
    header.Append("Index Key,");
    header.Append("CurrentBar,");
    header.Append("SignalCode,");
    header.Append("Open,");
    header.Append("High,");
    header.Append("Low,");
    header.Append("Close,");
    header.Append("BarCloseTime");

    //INPUT1
    for(int i = 1; i <= LookBack; i++)
    {
        signalCode.Append(input1_1_trendchar[i]);
        if(i == LookBack) signalCode.Append("-");
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= LookBack; i++)
    {
        signalCode.Append(input1_2_trendchar[i]);
        if(i == LookBack) signalCode.Append("-");
    }
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= LookBack; i++)
    {
        signalCode.Append(input1_3_trendchar[i]);
        if(i == LookBack) signalCode.Append("-");
    }
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= LookBack; i++)
    {
        signalCode.Append(input1_4_trendchar[i]);
        if(i == LookBack) signalCode.Append("-");
    }
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= LookBack; i++)
    {
        signalCode.Append(input2_1_trendchar[i]);
        if(i == LookBack) signalCode.Append("-");
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= LookBack; i++)
    {
        signalCode.Append(input2_2_trendchar[i]);
        if(i == LookBack) signalCode.Append("-");
    }
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= LookBack; i++)
    {
        signalCode.Append(input2_3_trendchar[i]);
        if(i == LookBack) signalCode.Append("-");
    }
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= LookBack; i++)
    {
        signalCode.Append(input2_4_trendchar[i]);
    }

    logEntry.Append(indexKey);
    logEntry.Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(CurrentBar-1);  
    logEntry.Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(signalCode.ToString());
    logEntry.Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(Open[1]);
    logEntry.Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(High[1]);
    logEntry.Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(Low[1]);
    logEntry.Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(Close[1]);
    logEntry.Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(Time[1]);
    indexKey++;
    
     try
        {
            if (File.Exists(fullPath) == false)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fullPath, true))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(header); // If file doesnt exist, create it and add the Header
                    sw.WriteLine(logEntry); // Append a new line to the file
                    sw.Close(); // Close the file to allow future calls to access the file again.
                }
            }
            else //File Does Exisit
            {
                if (IsFileLocked(fullPath) == false) //If file is not locked for editing
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fullPath, true))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(logEntry); // Append a new line to the file
                        sw.Close(); // Close the file to allow future calls to access the file again.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Outputs the error to the log
            //Log(uniqueStrategy + ": ExecutionLog - cannot write and read at the same time.", NinjaTrader.Cbi.LogLevel.Error);
            Print("ERROR WRITTING SignalLog");
        }
```

Comment: too many loops for a single operation! This might be a design issue. You must share all related code including the code where you handle the input to store them in arrays ! as it seems you're using an array for each column in the csv. Also, explain why you need to store it in memory ? what's your goal by storing it in memory rather than buffering it to disk ?

Comment: The loops are to generate the signal code and are necessary. The signal code is what is going to be eventually written to disk. Below is an example of a row   
  
ZZZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZ-BBAAAABBBB-ZBAAAAAAZZ-CCBCCXYZZZ-XXCXXYYZZZ-BBBBBBBBCC 1.1748 1.1748 1.17475 1.17475 10/5/2020 0:02'
  
Yes, each column refers to a data in an array. 
  
I run this code with historical data in an array and it takes an long time because of all in I/O operations R/W to disk. What I would like is for the data to be written into a memorystream and written only once.

Comment: This is why we need to see the related code to this part. As you can simply use models instead of multiple arrays, which would give you more managed structure to your data for more maintainability.

Comment: we need more code around this.  Why can't you just keep the filestream open?  Why do you need to close it?  What is all the loops and, I assume, arrays in the loops?  Hard to give better options when just a small subsection of code.

Comment: Example of fast CSV builder [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/249247/226545). Btw, you may use some existing CSV tool e.g. CSVHelper.

Comment: This is a ninjascript that runs within NinjaTrader. I do not have access to what goes on in the background. I can only access the data in the arrays as shown above. With each new bar/entry, a calc. is preformed and the  WriteToCSV function is called. The WriteToCSV is called thousands of times after each calculation. The loops are necessary to compile the data, they are not the issue. The issue is the thousands of times it opens, reads,writes and closes the file on the harddisk. I would like to have it save all the entries into memory and just dump the entire csv file to disk once.

Comment: I do not have all the data to be written to the csv at any given time. Each entry is built dynamically  in a sequence.

Comment: Instead of strings with a length of one character, it is better to use char. In other words, replace double quotes with single ones. `Append(",")` => `Append(',')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My try to prettify the code. Some comments inside.

```cs
private void WriteToCSV2()
{
    if (CurrentBar <= BarsRequiredToPlot + LookBack) return;

    StringBuilder logEntry = new StringBuilder();

    string fullPath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);

    // don't need a Stringbuilder to build a constant string
    const string header = "Index Key,CurrentBar,SignalCode,Open,High,Low,Close,BarCloseTime";

    // StringBuilder has Fluent API, it means you may write like .Append.Append.Append...
    logEntry.Append(indexKey).Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(CurrentBar - 1).Append(",");

    var trendchars = new[] // let's make an array of it ...
    {
        input1_1_trendchar,
        input1_2_trendchar,
        input1_3_trendchar,
        input1_4_trendchar,
        input2_1_trendchar,
        input2_2_trendchar,
        input2_3_trendchar,
        input2_4_trendchar
    };

    foreach (var trendchar in trendchars) // ... and process it in a loop
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= LookBack; i++)
        {
            logEntry.Append(trendchar[i]);
        }
        logEntry.Append("-");
    }
    logEntry.Remove(logEntry.Length - 1, 1); // cut the last redundant "-"
           
    logEntry.Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(Open[1]).Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(High[1]).Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(Low[1]).Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(Close[1]).Append(",");
    logEntry.Append(Time[1]);
    indexKey++;

    try
    {
        // "something == false" may be written as "!something"
        if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            File.WriteAllLines(fullPath, new[] { header, logEntry.ToString() });
        }
        else
        {
            // Warning! If the file is locked, here you may loose all the data to write
            if (!IsFileLocked(fullPath))
            {
                File.AppendAllLines(fullPath, new[] { logEntry.ToString() });
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // e.Message will tell what's exactly went wrong
        Print($"ERROR WRITTING SignalLog: {e.Message}");
    }
}
```

Possibly I've processed not all the things to optimize but only visible part of code.

---

Btw if you want write to disk once, you may try single `StringBuilder`, something like this:

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
const string header = ...
if (!File.Exists(filename))
{
    sb.AppendLine(header);
}

for (...)
{
    WriteToCSV2(sb);
    sb.AppendLine();
}

File.AppendAllText(filename, sb.ToString());
```

And change signature of the method

```
private void WriteToCSV2(StringBuilder logEntry)
{
    //...
}
```

`MemoryStream` would be a kind of redundancy here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. I was able to dramatically make it more efficient by creating models and using CSVhelper. https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ to export all the historical records to disk, only once during transitioning to realtime. Much faster.

```
var trendchars = new[] // array of arrays
{
    input1_1_trendchar,
    input1_2_trendchar,
    input1_3_trendchar,
    input1_4_trendchar,
    input2_1_trendchar,
    input2_2_trendchar,
    input2_3_trendchar,
    input2_4_trendchar
};
    
foreach (var trendchar in trendchars) // ... and process it in a loop
{   
    for (int i = 1; i <= LookBack; i++)
    {
        signalCode.Append(trendchar[i]);
    }
    signalCode.Append("-");
}
    
signalCode.Remove(signalCode.Length - 1, 1); // cut the last redundant "-"
```